# Understading ART / Dalvik compilation correctly

Tags: java, android, compilation, dalvik, art-runtime

I want to ask you if I understand the compiling process correctly.

After exporting Android app into .apk file we receive **byte code** (.apk).

When we want to launch our app on Android device:

**Dalvik:**

> byte code (.apk) -> Dalvik VM JIT compilation -> compiled native code
>   -> execution of the programme (whole programme is allocated in the memory)

This Dalvik JIT compilation is executed each time we lauch the app.

**ART:**

Installation:

> byte code (.apk) -> ART VM AOT compilation -> compiled native code

App launch:

> native code -> execution (only some part of the programme allocates
>   memory)

AOT compilation is proccessed only once after app installation.

Comment: Dalvik JIT is truly just-in-time, and so AFAIK it is only run on "hot spots" in code. AFAIK the entire APK is not loaded into memory. Beyond that, you may want to watch the YouTube video of the 2014 Google I|O conference session on ART, once it is available, after the June 25-26 conference.